# Yup Validation Errors not being triggered in React Hook Form Component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hook-form, yup

I just updated my sign-in form to incorporate Yup and React-Hook-Form. The issue seems to be that the validation errors are not being triggered or passed to the UI.

I have included the code from my component below.

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { useCallback, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { getSession, signIn } from 'next-auth/react'
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form'
import Button from '../components/Button'
import * as yup from 'yup'
import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/yup'

import Input from '../components/Input'

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const session = await getSession(context)

  if (session) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: '/',
        permanent: false,
      },
    }
  }

  return {
    props: {},
  }
}

const authSchema = yup.object().shape({
  name: yup.string().when('variant', {
    is: 'register',
    then: yup
      .string()
      .min(3, 'Name must be at least 3 characters')
      .required('Name is required'),
  }),
  email: yup.string().email('Invalid email').required('Email is required'),
  password: yup
    .string()
    .min(6, 'Password must be at least 6 characters')
    .required('Password is required'),
})

const Auth = () => {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    setValue,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(authSchema),
  })

  const [variant, setVariant] = useState('login')

  const toggleVariant = useCallback(() => {
    setVariant((currentVariant) =>
      currentVariant === 'login' ? 'register' : 'login'
    )
  }, [])

  const handleLogin = async (data) => {
    try {
      await signIn('credentials', {
        email: data.email,
        password: data.password,
        redirect: false,
        callbackUrl: '/',
      })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }

  const handleRegister = async (data) => {
    try {
      await axios.post('/api/register', {
        email: data.email,
        name: data.name,
        password: data.password,
      })

      handleLogin(data)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    register('name')
    register('email')
    register('password')
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="h-screen w-full">
      <div className="bg-white w-full h-full lg:bg-opacity-50">
        <nav className="px-12 py-5">
          <img src="/header.svg" className="h-12" alt="Logo" />
        </nav>
        <div className="flex justify-center">
          <form
            className="bg- px-16 py-16 self-center mt-2 lg:w-2/5 lg:max-w-md rounded-md w-full"
            onSubmit={handleSubmit(
              variant === 'login' ? handleLogin : handleRegister
            )}
          >
            <h2 className="text-zinc-500 text-4xl mb-8 font-semibold">
              {variant === 'login' ? 'Sign in' : 'Register'}
            </h2>
            <div className="flex flex-col gap-4">
              {variant === 'register' && (
                <div>
                  {errors.name && (
                    <p className="text-red-500">{errors.name.message}</p>
                  )}
                  <Input
                    id="name"
                    type="text"
                    label="Name"
                    onChange={(e) => setValue('name', e.target.value)}
                  />
                </div>
              )}
              <p>{errors.email?.message}</p>
              <Input
                id="email"
                type="email"
                label="Email Address"
                onChange={(e) => setValue('email', e.target.value)}
              />
              <p>{errors.password?.message}</p>
              <Input
                type="password"
                id="password"
                label="Password"
                onChange={(e) => setValue('password', e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>
            <Button
              onClick={variant === 'login' ? handleLogin : handleRegister}
              primary
              modifier={'w-full mt-16'}
            >
              {variant === 'login' ? 'Login' : 'Sign up'}
            </Button>
            <p className="text-neutral-500 mt-12">
              {variant === 'login'
                ? 'New to the application?'
                : 'Already have an account?'}
              <span
                onClick={toggleVariant}
                className="text-neutral-500 ml-1 hover:underline cursor-pointer"
              >
                {variant === 'login' ? 'Create an account' : 'Login'}
              </span>
            </p>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Auth
```

The Errors object is displaying to the console, but remains empty. I have tried updating the Yup schema, but that doesn't seem to be changing anything. I was also concerned that it may be tied to the way I handled form register, because I didn't use forwardRef. However, that does not seem to be the case either.

Any insights on this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Adding the shouldValidate prop to setValue seems to be the solution. 

https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/setvalue/